# IoC, Containers, and NServiceBus confusion

Tags: design-patterns, ioc-container, nservicebus

Here is my setup

- Castle Windsor is my container
- NServiceBus is itself using it's own container internally, Spring by default
- I'm implementing the PubSub config.

Ok, if I have my Bus.Publish happening within my IWantToRunAtStartup class, then everything is fine. As a test for example on Run() we can start a timer and it'll go into a Service style loop.

However, what if I want to abstract NServiceBus from my app, and have my app go:

```
new CustomPulisherClass().Notify(ISomeMessage msg);
```

In this situation, how do I implement CustomPublisherClass.

My confusion is coming from the fact that NServiceBus is already running as a Service, it's already been "Started". How to I get at the correct instance of the Bus object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure NServiceBus to use Windsor as the internal container:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nservicebus/index.php?title=Additional_containers

If you do that the correct IBus will be available in your instance of Windsor

Comment: how do you mean? I would just have to get my current instance of the container, and go .Resolve<IBus>()? without having to configure IBus in my windsor.config?

Comment: Also, Andreas, how would that work when NServiceBus is running under a separate process... i.e. a service? can that work?

Comment: Yes the bus would be available using .Resolve

Not following you on the other q: You always communicate using an instance of the bus running in the same process as your own code. 

Eg. If you have a webb app sending commands to a backend service hosted in the NSB generic host you would configure NSB in you web app as well and do a bus.Send(new WhateverMessage())

Inshort: NSB always run in the same process as you code that interacts with the bus

Does this help?

Comment: yep, perfect, thanks andreas. I think I got a bit confused, but I just wanted some confirmation from someone else. good stuff!